# Integrating a C applet into a Python app (GTK)

Tags: python, c, gtk

I've got a Python/GTK project I've been working on for a while, and some of the functionality I want already exists in Gnome panel applets.  Based on my reading, panel applets are already in a subclass of the standard GTK Bin, so I would think there'd be a way that I can use the C-based GTK objects in my Python-based application.

For instance, I've got the fish applet in /usr/lib/gnome-panel/fish-applet-2 as a binary

Can I do some GTK magic to get that object so it can be embedded into my Python/GTK gui?

I'm not expecting a step-by-step walkthrough, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for applets in gnome panel is quite complex. It's based on the gnome Bonobo framework (which in turn is based on CORBA). But now the whole thing is in a bit of a flux because gnome is moving away from Bonobo to a new dbus-based design. So if it's loading existing gnome panel applets you want you should absolutely use the code from gnome panel to do it. There is (or at least was) an example program included that does nothing but load an applet into a window.

If you want to display a widget from one of your own programs (a custom applet) inside another of your programs it's much easier. There are a set of widgets called [GtkSocket](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkSocket.html) and [GtkPlug](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkPlug.html) for this purpose. Of course the to programs doesn't need to run on the same machine. But there is always the delicate problem of getting them together in the first place.